# Where am I? A scene of death

Tags: language, geography, word-problem, history

[image]

Hint (for those of you who are stuck):

> Il faut regarder plus attentivement.

In this question, I have given a total of 5 hints (or even more).

Once you have the answer, please include how these hints worked.

Comment: Unfortunately my French is pretty bad. So if it's wrong, I'd appreciate it if someone could help me correct it

Comment: To clarify about the French, it is meant to translate to "It is necessary to look closer"

Comment: In addition - whoever made the edit please do NOT without permission. I know what I'm doing, thank you very much.

Comment: Is there a clue in the image itself beyond just the text? If so, this should probably have the steganography tag.

Comment: I'm not really willing to disclose any specific details, but I shall say that analysis of the image (using some program/whtver) will most probably not help very much.

Comment: I have to go, soon, so I can't look into this, further, right now.  However, if you zoom into the picture, some of the letters are queer.  For example, if you look at the phrase `also leper elsewhere` the first two `L`s are made from a light brown line on the left, with a dark brown line on the right.  The 3rd `L` is made from faint brown line on the left,  a dark brown line in the middle, and a light brown one on the right.  Normally, I wouldn't think a font would make this mistake.  The `L` in place is similarly done.  It could just be compression - but might be intentional.

Comment: I'm not sure about the colours - as far as I can see it's all black. I simply typed the message and then screenshotted the preview on SE.

Comment: I feel like Gamow's answer is pretty sufficient to get the checkmark.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This place is

> the city **Ypres** in Belgium (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ypres)

### Explanation:

A scene of death a century ago,

> **Ypres Salient** (the area around city Ypres) was the scene of some of the biggest battles in the first world war

and also Ieper elsewhere

> The Flemish name of **Ypres** is **Ieper** (https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ieper)
>  The language tag hints at Dutch name versus French name

Il faut regarder plus attentivement.

> It is easy to misread **Ieper** (starting with capital-I) for **leper** (starting with little-ell).

Comment: Very nice! See if you can explain the other clues I hid in the question too.

Comment: Dang, I can't believe I didn't see you'd posted this already :( so are you saying there are at least two more hints in the question?

Comment: Actually, only one of my 5 hints have been explained so far which is "Il fat regarded plus attentivement" (The literal meaning of the hint I gave)

Comment: Also, as has been mentioned elsewhere, the language of this hint is another hint. (French speaking country)

Comment: I'll accept Gamow's answer once all of the hints have been explained (whether by Gamow or anyone else). If anyone else spots some of them, then feel free to post in a separate answer, as spotting these hints was part of the puzzle.

Answer (score 4):

I would say this is

> The Prestige

(/!\ spoiler)

"A scene of death" :

> The magician (Alfred Borden / Christian Bale) dies on **scene** during his magic trick.

"a century ago" :

> The movie took place a century ago.

"Where am I" in the title

> the magician does an great magic trick called 'The Transported Man' where he disappears on scene.

The hint :

> The movie starts by "Are you watching carefully" and the sentence in french can be translated by "You need to watch more carefully". (why use french here ?)

I still can't explain the "leper" part.

> edit : May be because Robert Angier (Hugh Jackman) has lost two fingers ?

Comment: Sorry - but no :) Nice try

Comment: I've clarified about the french in order to prevent confusion with translation

Answer (score 3):

I believe this refers to

> Verdun, site of a major battle in 1916 the site of a leper house in the 7th century. My guess is that the hint is in French because Verdun is located in France.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not the answer. Nice one spotting that the location may be in France due to the language of the hint. However, I will say that there is another reason for the choice of language, and though French is not necessarily the language spoken in that place, it is one of the languages of the country the place is in.